# WordPress Custom Fields get post from page

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a WordPress website and i have a little problem with the custom fields plugin. I'm familiar with plugin and worked with it few times before.

I created a custom field for posts and a custom field for pages.
When i try to get the page's custom field i get it with no problem.
The page has global $post on top and i do get a different $post->ID
for each post loaded.

```
$pageMonth = get_field('page-month');
```

But when i try to get the post's field i get nothing.. I also tried it through
the post's loop with $post->ID

```
<?php $postMonth = get_field('post-month', $post->ID); ?>
```

I checked myself few times, the custom field names are fine and i did
attached the post and the page to their custom fields and everything..

Comment: Are you try echo the value?  echo $postMonth

Comment: I tried, pageMonth works but postMonth doesn't get anything and i don't understand why

Comment: The code is inside a page template file and i'm trying to get the post's field into it but there is a global $post declared and i am trying to pull the field from the loop